# Can this feature be used as input to cnn based on the q-q plot?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, normal-distribution, normalization, learning

I have normalised my input features and target variable using the quantile transform by sklearn. The Q-Q plot of one of the feature after normalisation is given as below. Is this feature normalised? Can I use it for training the cnn model?

[image]